# Google Chrome Extension - simple jQuery to open a tags in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink, preventdefault

I'd like to open links in my chrome extension without having to type chrome.tabs.create and stuff, but why doesn't this work? It doesn't return an error.

```
$("a").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: $(this).attr("href") });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo, e.preventDefault is a function, so you should call it with some "()"

But if you just want to open a tab from your extension, simply set a target="_blank" attribute on the anchor tag.

Comment: It wasn't the preventDefault, but the _blank did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Change:
e.preventDefault;

To:
e.preventDefault();
```